# Does hibernate set back reference in @OneToMany @ManyToOne relationship automatically?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have Order entity that has `orderItems` list.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy ="order")
List<OrderItem> orderItems;
```

`OrderItem` has back reference to Order

```
@ManyToOne
Order order;
```

When I save `Order` should I manually set backreference in `OrderItem` entity?
Like this

```
OrderItem orderItem1 = new OrderItem( //constructor );
OrderItem orderItem2 = new OrderItem( //constructor );
List orderItems = Arrays.asList(orderItem1, orderItem2);
Order order = new Order( orderItems);

orderItems.forEach(orderItem -> orderItem.setOrder(order); // like this?
```

Do Hibernate and Spring data jpa set it automatically?

Comment: as you have `mappedBy` specified no you don't have to.  More here https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-joincolumn-vs-mappedby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For creating and updating case , they will not help you to set it automatically and you have to configure the relationship by yourself.

The `mappedBy` here is to define whether `Order.orderItems` or `OrderItem.order` is to used to provide the value for the corresponding DB column that link between them. (i.e. `order_id` column in `order_item` table).

If `mappedBy` is defined , `OrderItem.order` will be used to provide the value for the relationship. Otherwise , `Order.orderItems` will be used.

For the loading case , it will help you to set it automatically.